# Почему в данном примере текстовое поле выходит за границы контейнера?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="container">
    <select></select>
    <input type="textfield"></input>
</div>


div{
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}

select  {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    width: 100%;
}

input {
  width:100%;  
}
```

Если я выставляю input {width:99%;} То ширина поля получается 350,5 пикселов. Гугл хром окруляет в большую сторону. Не получается, в общем.

Comment: Вероятно из-за бордера... можно покопаться в сторону `box-sizing`

Comment: у вас какой то странный код html :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ширина рассчитывается без учета границ элемента по дефолту. А раз у вас есть границы, то надо переопределить алгоритм расчета. Ставите box-sizing: border-box;

```css
div{
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}

select  {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    width: 100%;
}

input {
  width:100%;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <select></select>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`* {
box-sizing:border-box;
}`
добавьте этот свойство внутри стили css